# How to center single-column pgfplots bar graph in two column document

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

How do I center a single-column `pgfplots`/`tikzpicture` bar graph in a two column document?

Here is an example document. The graph is taken from the [example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Pgfplots_package#Bar_graphs) at Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% Some Text

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=.7,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156) (2008,415 838)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972) (2008,398866)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% More Text

\end{document}
```

And here is the sample compiled document. The misaligned graph is shown. I do want the graph to be in a single column, but as you can see the graph is not centered. (Probably because of the ylabel on the left).

[image: Sample document]

Comment: Why do not use `twocolumn` option in `article` class instead of `\multicolumn`?

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thanks. Actually I am using this in a `IEEEtran` document, if that changes anything. This is my attempt at creating a minimal reproducible example. I have changed my question to reflect this.

Comment: @krismath Confirm whether you need to place the image exactly as you shown else top/bottom placement also fine?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to centre the graphic in its column, or across both columns?

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Put your `tikzpicture` in `figure` environment. `\begin{figure}[h] \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture} \end{figure}`

Comment: @ferahfeza Thanks. Can you make it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your tikzpicture in figure environment like:

```
\begin{figure}[h] 
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % Some text.

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=.7,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156) (2008,415 838)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972) (2008,398866)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]% Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish you the best of success :-)